# How to install things needed into halyard docker container

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I'm trying to setup Spinnaker a the local development environment.

I'm following the steps here: https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/halyard/.

In the 'Local Git' section (https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/environment/) it includes instructions to install a bunch of stuff with sudo.
However sudo doesnt seem to be installed.

> bash: sudo: command not found

(and is not in /usr/bin either)

Should I install sudo? If so, is there some default root pw I should know about?

Comment: Are you inside a container or non-standard Unix machine? Docker doesn't have sudo. Those set of instructions are to build from scratch, not using the pre-existing image

Comment: I am on the container I started up as described in step '1. Install Halyard' in those instructions.

Comment: I see 5 numbers under Docker section. None say sudo... The "Install on Ubuntu" section does https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/halyard/#install-halyard-on-docker

Comment: The sudo installs I was referring to was under the '3. Choose your Environment ' and then 'Local Git'.

Comment: All of that assumes you are in Debian or Ubuntu for installing Spinnaker, not within the Halyard Docker container. In any case, most containers by default start as root, so you wouldn't need sudo. For example, `apt-get install x` will already work - see https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#sort-multi-line-arguments  In other words, Halyard is a standalone container for setting up Spinnaker. You wouldn't put them in the same container

Comment: Ok thanks for that @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the halyard image with the required stuff that you need